# Android: can't replace one fragment with another

Tags: android, replace, android-fragments

I need to replace a `Fragment` in one `Activity` with another `Fragment`, below is the layer file of the `Activity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/home_layout_container">

    <fragment android:name="com.foo.FragA"
        android:id="@+id/home_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

so by default there is **FragA**, now I want to replace it with **FragB** in activity, I did:

```
public void onRegionClicked(Region region) {
    RegionInfoFragment rif = RegionInfoFragment.newInstance(region);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.home_list, rif);
}
```

But I got exception:

```
>6:24:40.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1857)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1752)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1709)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1689)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:743)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:933)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:578)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1219)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:380)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-06 16:24:40.692: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9194):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I did not miss ft.commit() in code, and got the above exception.

Comment: This video shows how its done: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUNsFhcZNAo)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You cannot replace a fragment defined statically in the layout file. You can only replace fragments that you added dynamically via a `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to add them programmatically.

Comment: Can anyone provide a link showing the proper way to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: @James - Take a look at the [Fragment Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). Look at the code snippet under, **"Or, programmatically add the fragment to an existing ViewGroup."**

Comment: use this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace

Comment: Why do the dynamically added fragments overlap some time??

Comment: @NightCrawler getSupportFragmentManager and getChildFragmentManager have a slight difference described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14775322/2468026) and using them together can create an overlapping fragment.

Comment: This comment held true.  Change the fragment creation away from static xml declaration and use the FragmentTransaction to add it.  Also, when replacing the fragment using FragmentTransaction be sure to use the container holding the fragment as the first param to replace() instead of passing in the id of the actual fragment.  See section "Performing Fragment Transactions" in the link provided by @PeterAjtai

Comment: this article provides the solution : http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/dynamically-add-fragments-to-an-activity-in-android/

Answer (score 5):

Try to `commit()` at the end of the ft, you need to `commit()` your changes to let it know.

Answer (score 1):

```
getFragmentManger()
  .beginTransaction
  .replace(R.id.frame,Yourfragment.newInstance(),null)
  .addtobackstack
  .commit();
```

People always say I am one-liner, so here is one-liner solution for you

Comment: Sorry, need to scroll to see one-line code, so i edited

Comment: this is not valid in androidx