# Fragment update with a new fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a layout of

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout13" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingRight="70dp" android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingLeft="70dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/baby_icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/baby" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <fragment
        android:name="com.nicu.health.FragAFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/yellow_cardlist_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

On the startup this does show the correct fragment(FragAFragment). Now on the button click for `baby_icon` I try to remove the current fragment and add a new one(FragBFragment) which has an entirely different layout.

Though I see that the `onCreateView` method is called and it does return a non-null view but the UI on the screen of the new fragment does not get updated. I use the below code to update the fragment.

```
                        Fragment baby = FragBFragment.newInstance(1);
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//                  ft.remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yellow_cardlist_fragment));
//                  ft.add(R.id.yellow_cardlist_fragment, baby);
                    ft.replace(R.id.yellow_cardlist_fragment, baby);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Code for commit = "+ft.commit());
```

I had tried all combinations of remove, replace and add to get the fragment thing workng, but in vain!

Also further I tried with the code as

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.nicu.health.FragBFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/yellow_cardlist_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
```

and this does work to show the second fragment on startup!!!!

Help will be reeally appreicated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer to my question is

[Android: can't replace one fragment with another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907673/android-cant-replace-one-fragment-with-another/5907704#5907704)

I added dynamic fragments on start of the main activity and onclick I did a ft.replace to replace the old fragment!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my first guess: You forgot to say ft.commit();

My second guess:

Lets say u have Activity AB which controls Fragment A and Fragment B.

You also have 3 layouts. Layout_ActivityAB, Layout_FragA, Layout_FragB.

So setContentView(R.layout.Layout_ActivityAB) is called inside Activity AB. That will be the layout in which u tell android where to place the fragment in the screen.

Inside Fragment A or Fragment B:

```
@Override
    //onCreateView is called when an instance of this class is first created.
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Layout_FragA, container, false);  return rootView;
    }
```

R.layout.Layout_FragA is called inside the Fragment. Layout_FragA is the actual content of the Fragment.