# What is difference between getSupportFragmentManager() and getChildFragmentManager()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

My class inherits Fragment and that's why it can't use getSupportFragmentManager(). 
I am using getChildFragmentManager and it is showing me Error - IllegalArguementException: No view found for id... error.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Code for calling AttachmentsListFragment is

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("AttachmentsList", msg.attachments);  
        AttachmentListFragment listfrag = new AttachmentListFragment(msg.attachments);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();       
transaction.add(R.id.attachmentslistcontainer, listfrag);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

attachmentslayout.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/attachmentslistcontainer"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAttachmentHeader"
        style="@style/Normal.Header.Toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/list_separator_background"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="@string/attachments_header"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

AttachmentsListFragment.java

```
public class AttachmentListFragment extends ListFragment implements IAttachmentsData {

    ArrayList<Attachments> items = null;
    Integer cellLayoutID;
    Integer index;

    public AttachmentListFragment() {

    }

    public AttachmentListFragment(ArrayList<Attachments> items) {
        this.items = items;
        Log.i("Logging", "Items size" + items.size()); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        //  setContentView(R.layout.attachmentslayout);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attachmentslayout, container, false);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new AttachmentAdapter(
                getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.attachmentslistcellcontent,
                items));
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        index = position;
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putByteArray("Data", items.get(position).getImageData());
        intent.putExtras(b);
    }


    public byte[] getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (items != null && index < items.size()) {

            return items.get(index).getImageData();
        }
            return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the entire method and/or class where you are calling "getChildFragmentManager".

Answer (score 171, accepted):

The definition of `getChildFragmentManager()` is:

> Return a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments
>   inside of this Fragment.

Meanwhile the definition of `getFragmentManager()` (or in this case `getSupportFragmentManager()`) is:

> Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated
>   with this fragment's activity.

Basically, the difference is that Fragment's now have their own internal `FragmentManager` that can handle Fragments.  The child FragmentManager is the one that handles Fragments contained within only the Fragment that it was added to.  The other FragmentManager is contained within the entire `Activity`.

In this case, what I'm guessing is you've added the Fragments to the Activity's FragmentManager.  You get the child FragmentManager which doesn't contain what you are looking for.  Thus you get the exception because it can't find the Fragment with the given ID because it's in a different FragmentManager.

Comment: I tried using getChildFragmentManager. But it also shows same exception

Comment: I thought you said you were already using getChildFragmentManager.

Comment: if I use the getSupportFragmentManager to create a child fragment so that the parent holds the child and both are visible/in-the-foreground, what does the back button do? does it pop off the parent? or the child? etc.?

Comment: @Rai  `getSupportFragmentManager` and `getFragmentManager` are both fragment managers on the top level `Activity`.  The Fragment you add technically is not a "child fragment" by the definition described here. They are Fragments handled by the Activity. Any Fragment you post on the backstack of either manager handled by the Activity will be popped off on "back".

Answer (score 35):

`getFragmentManager` belong to `Activity`
`getChildFragmentManager` belong to `Fragment`

Example we have a app which have `MainActivity`, `Fragment1`, `Fragment2`, `container_view_on_main` is a layout in `activty_main.xml`

**TO display** `Fragment1` on `MainActivity` we **must** use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_view_on_main, Fragment1.newInstance());
```

**TO display** `Fragment2` from `Fragment1` we have 2 way

USE `getFragmentManager()`

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_view_on_main, Fragment1.newInstance());
```

USE `getChildFragmentManager()`

First, we have to create a layout with id `container_view_on_fragment1` inside `fragment1.xml`, then

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_view_on_fragment1, Fragment2.newInstance()).commit();
```

**CONCLUSION**

In this demo, I think we should use `getFragmentManager()` when go from `Fragment1` to `Fragment2` because it is simple and good for performance (`Fragment1` will stop when `Fragment2` open)

*When we use `getChildFragmentManager()`?*
Example your `MainActivity` have a `ViewPager` which have 3 pages, inside each pages you need to replace some fragment.

**MORE**
**- getParentFragment()**
`getFragmentManager()`  => return null
`getChildFragmentManager()`  => always return root fragment (`Fragment1` in demo even we go to Fragment3,,... )

This answer is base on my understand so please correct me if I am wrong.
Hope it help

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have a fragment which behaves as a container of fragments you must use the getChildFragmentManager method of the fragment. If you use the getSupportFragmentManager you will basically use the fragment manager which behaves the way the activity lifecycle goes, not the way your fragment does.

For example I had a fragment which contained a ViewPager – it is called CollectionsFragment. So I had 3 fragments displayed as tabs in it: AllCollectionsFragment, MyCollectionsFragment, FavouriteCollectionsFragment. And I gave the getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() to the FragmentStatePagerAdapter which I was using.

So this was causing the following behavior – the onDestroyView/onDestroy/onDetach/onStop methods of the 3 tab fragments not to be called. When I changed to use the getChildFragmentManager everything was OK.

If you want you can check the docs for the two methods:

getChildFragmentManager():
Return a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments inside of this Fragment.

getSupportFragmentManager():
Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated with this fragment’s activity.