# Invoking a method from parent fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, dialog

Normally, from an `Activity` I could invoke an object that extends `DialogFragment` and implements `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()`.

Then if I wanted to, from that `Dialog`, invoke a method in the parent activity, I could do `((NameOfParentActivity)getActivity()).nameOfMethod();`

But now I am invoking such an object from a `Fragment` (specifically, a page of a `ViewPager`) instead of an `Activity`.

I'm not exactly sure what to change to get the method-calling line to work. In other words I am trying to call a method from the `Fragment` class, while inside its `DialogFragment` object.

Edit: `OnClick()` code from my `Adapter` class:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    DeleteGameBoardDialogFragment dialogFragment = new DeleteGameBoardDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(TabFragmentGameBoard.GAMEBOARD_DIALOG_TAG, mGameBoards.get(position).getGameBoardName());
    dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
    dialogFragment.show(((Activity) mContext).getFragmentManager(), "");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your issue with [setTargetFragment()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment(android.app.Fragment,%20int)) and  [getParentFragment()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getParentFragment()) to your dialog Fragment.

Call dialog  from your **ViewPager fragment**, where you want execute a fragment method.

```
DeleteGameBoardDialogFragment dialogFragment = new DeleteGameBoardDialogFragment();
dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this,1);
FragmentTransaction transaction=getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();//must be getChildFragmentManager()
dialogFragment.show(transaction, "df");
```

And inside of your `DeleteGameBoardDialogFragment`, call below code

```
DeleteGameBoardDialogFragment  fragment=(DeleteGameBoardDialogFragment) getParentFragment();
fragment.nameOfMethod()
```

**IMPT:**  make sure you call dialog from a **fragment only** and not from activity. **Why** If you call from activity `getParentFragment()` returns `null`.

> getParentFragment () : Returns the parent Fragment containing this Fragment. If this Fragment is attached directly to an Activity, returns null.. more visit [SO : getParentFragment returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804526/getparentfragment-returning-null)

Comment: Hi @Bharatesh after calling `setTargetFragment` in mainfragment, when I call this `((MainFragment)getTargetFragment()).method();` it is working. Is this a good way to do it

Comment: @a2en no issues.. only difference is that I have created a object and called a method and you don't.. however its your call how you do it. Code readability is important.

Comment: but you are calling  `getParentFragment();` and i called `getTargetFragment`

Comment: I missed it... Please check difference between [getParentFragment()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getParentFragment()) and [getTargetFragment()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getTargetFragment()) on official documentation. as both methods depends on implementing child fragment.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question, you have a `ViewPager` that opens a dialog when a button is clicked, and you wanted to access a method from your `ViewPager Fragment`?

If this is your question, might as well try making an `Interface` that behaves like a `Listener` and pass it on the `DialogFragment`. The `Fragment` where your method is, should implement this listener.