# Get last fragment by tag

Tags: android, android-fragments

I add fragments to back stack. For instance: `A, B, C, A, D`. Then from `D` I want to update the second `A`.

If I use `supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("A")`, I have a reference to the first `A`, that is in a bottom of the back stack.

I tried to search through `fragments` collection, [`getBackStackEntryAt(i)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13304102/2914140), but with no success.

Comment: Currently I use `parentFragment` and `childFragmentManager` to access previous fragment, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804526/getparentfragment-returning-null.

Comment: Sorry, `findFragmentByTag("A")` often references to the last "A", but not always. If I add many fragments, it can link to not last "A". This behaviour is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, looking at [get the latest fragment in backstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702216/get-the-latest-fragment-in-backstack) I understood that `findFragmentByTag(tag)` finds the last fragment with required `tag`. In my case after adding many fragments it sometimes found *not last fragment with `tag`*, but a *previous* to last (with the same `tag`). Maybe there is a bug in my code, I don't know, why is that.

First I tried to use callbacks, then tried to use `parentFragment` and `childFragmentManager`, see [getParentFragment returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804526/getparentfragment-returning-null). In fragment `D` I called `parentFragment` and accessed to methods of `A` and could update the last `A` fragment. This solution has two problems.

1) Child fragment (`D`) inherits a toolbar from parent (`A`) and adds own buttons. And after clicking `Back` button we return not to a parent, but even quit parent (`A`).

2) If we want to update not previous fragment (so that between A and D are also 3 fragments), it seems to be impossible.

So, I cancelled that solution and changed the application behaviour. I clear a backstack where it is possible. So that we cannot have two `A` fragments in backstack. I use `supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)`. Yes, that's a workaround, but I don't know, how to deal with that bug.