# IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id , When coming back from another fragment and onResume calls

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a fragment that most of  it's layout is creating **programmatically**.

First time that fragment appears everything is OK but when I open another fragment and press **back button** I got IllegalArgumentException.

Please note that Just when I press back button this issue happens , When I call **popBackStack** everything is ok.

Any suggestion ?

Code :

```
if(mapView != null)
{
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mapView.getParent();
    if (parent != null)
    {
        parent.removeView(mapView);
    }
}
try
{
    // Creating view
    mapView = getBaseActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.property_show_map_section, (ViewGroup) view, false);
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
((LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.section_container)).addView(mapView);
final SupportMapFragment googleMap = new SupportMapFragment();
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.map_container, googleMap).commit();
```

LogCat :

```
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b00e4 (com.example.app:id/map_container) for fragment SupportMapFragment{53056b1c #0 id=0x7f0b00e4}
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:939)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1917)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1800)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:967)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:957)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1541)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManager.java:493)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-19 18:28:40.229: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to override the `onBackPressed()` method in your second activity.

If you are in a fragment, you can might do:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

                return true
        }
        return false;
}
```

Or, you might try to change the `getChildFragmentManager()` to `getFragmentManager()` or `getSupportFragmentManager()`, if the code you posted is in an Activity.

`getChildFragmentManager()` is more for Fragment, and `getFragmentManager()` is more for Activity. You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14775322/4195406) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I am using above code in  a fragment , So I don't have access to `onBackPressed` , And I think it's not a good solution to override onBackPressed .

Comment: Is the code you posted from an Activity? Then you might change `getChildFragmentManager()` to `getFragmentManager()` or `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: +1 for your solution to override backpressed but I think Overriding back buttion to fix this issue is not a good solution. Thanks for your assist :)

Comment: Replacing getChildFragmentManager with getfragmentManager fixed the issue even now that I am coding inside a fragment instead of an Activity , Thanks ;)