# Nested Fragment does not show properly

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am running into an issue where I have a fragment, which contains a tab layout/view pager which handles 3 sub fragments, and when I open the main fragment the first time all the data in the sub fragments shows up properly, but when I re-open the main fragment again (clicking on a seperate listview item), the data does not get populated properly (even though it exists).

I also noticed that the only time the sub-fragment gets its data is when view paging over to the last tab,  or when rotating the screen. Also, when I try to move the screen to the right using the view pager the tab indicator will get stuck mid way between the first and second tab.

**What can I do to fix this issue?**

**Fragment Adapter**

```
public class DetailFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Plot", "Trailers", "Reviews" };
    private Movie movie;

    public DetailFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, Movie movie) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        this.movie = movie;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0){
            return PlotFragment.newInstance(movie);
        } else if (position == 1){
            return TrailerFragment.newInstance();
        } else if (position == 2){
            return ReviewFragment.newInstance();
        } else {
            Log.e("RETURNING NULL", "RETURNING NULL");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

**Main Fragment**

```
public class MovieItemDetailFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    public String TAG = MovieItemDetailFragment.class.getCanonicalName();

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private View view;
    private TextView tvTitle, tvReleaseDate, tvRating;
    private ImageView ivMoviePoster;
    private Movie movie;
    private Handler handler;

    private Button btnFavorite;
    private boolean isFavorited = false;

    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener;

    private ViewPager viewpager;
    private TabLayout tablayout;
    private DetailFragmentPagerAdapter adapter;


    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MovieItemDetailFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MovieItemDetailFragment fragment = new MovieItemDetailFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public MovieItemDetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_item_detail, container, false);
        init();
        return view;
    }

    private void init() {
        handler = new Handler();
        this.movie = (Movie) getArguments().getSerializable("MOVIE");


        tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvReleaseDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvReleaseDate);
        tvRating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAvgRating);
        ivMoviePoster = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivMoviePoster);
        btnFavorite = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFavorite);
        btnFavorite.setOnClickListener(this);

        viewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        tablayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);

        adapter = new DetailFragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
                getActivity(), getMovie());

        viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        tablayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);
            }
        });

        mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isFavorited = true;
                btnFavorite.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favorite_content_selector));
            }
        };

        setElementValues();
    }

    private void setElementValues() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tvTitle.setText(getMovie().getTitle());
                tvReleaseDate.setText(getMovie().getRelease_date());
                tvRating.setText(String.valueOf(getMovie().getVote_average()));


                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(getMovie().getFull_poster_path()).into(ivMoviePoster);

                if (isFavorited) {
                    btnFavorite.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favorite_content_selector));
                } else {
                    btnFavorite.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favorite_blank_content_selector));
                }

            }
        });

    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnFavorite:
                if (isFavorited) {
                    isFavorited = false;
                    btnFavorite.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favorite_blank_content_selector));
                    showSnackbar("I thought that was one of your favorites.");
                } else {
                    isFavorited = true;
                    btnFavorite.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favorite_content_selector));
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    private void showSnackbar(String msg) {
        Snackbar
                .make(view, msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction(R.string.snackbar_action, mOnClickListener)
                .setActionTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.material_yellow_400))
                .show();
    }


    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public Movie getMovie() {
        return movie;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling

```
adapter = new DetailFragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), getActivity(), getMovie());
```

try:

```
adapter = new DetailFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity(), getMovie());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also working for me.

Basically, the difference is that Fragment's now have their own internal **FragmentManager** that can handle Fragments. The child **FragmentManager** is the one that handles Fragments contained within only the Fragment that it was added to. The other **FragmentManager** is contained within the entire Activity.

for further detail about **getChildFragmentManager()**
visit this question

[[What is difference between getSupportFragmentManager() and getChildFragmentManager()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740445/what-is-difference-between-getsupportfragmentmanager-and-getchildfragmentmanag][1])