# Removed listview itmes when android device orientation changed

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment

I have a MainActivity with one fragment. I have a ListView in pager which is inside fragment of MainActivity. Now when device orientation is changed ListView is not showing any items that were shown before :

MainFragment.java :

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);

    if (myGrp == null)
                myGrp = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    mActivityAdapter = new MyGroupsAdapter(myContext, myGrp);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                    myContext.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // Show 3 total pages.
                return 3;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                    final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View dummyView = null;
                if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
                    dummyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_fragment,
                            container, false);
                    ListView mListView = (ListView) dummyView
                            .findViewById(R.id.inbox_listview);
                    mListView.setAdapter(inboxAdapter);
                    mListView
                            .setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                        View arg1, int position, long id) {
                                    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
                                    fragment.inboxItem_onLongClick(id);
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {
                    dummyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_fragment, container,
                            false);
                    ListView mListView = (ListView) dummyView
                            .findViewById(R.id.chatGroupList);
                    mListView.setAdapter(mActivityAdapter);
                } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3) {
                            //any things 
                      }
    }
}



@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences prfs = myContext.getSharedPreferences("user_info",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        GroupsSaved = prfs.getBoolean("GroupsSaved", false);

        if (myGrp == null || myGrp.size() == 0)
            getMyGroups();

        Global.nowChatGrpID = 0;
        mActivityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: post code of your activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your activity is reloaded when you change orientation, try to add this to your manifest:

```
     <activity android:name=".yourActivity" 
      android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
...
```

Solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code :

```
myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

to

```
getChildFragmentManager();
```

may this will work.

If you want to have a fragment which behaves as a container of fragments you must use the `getChildFragmentManager` method of the fragment. If you use the `getSupportFragmentManager` you will basically use the fragment manager which behaves the way the activity lifecycle goes, not the way your fragment does.

For example I had a fragment which contained a ViewPager – it is called CollectionsFragment. So I had 3 fragments displayed as tabs in it: AllCollectionsFragment, MyCollectionsFragment, FavouriteCollectionsFragment. And I gave the `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` to the FragmentStatePagerAdapter which I was using.

So this was causing the following behaviour – the `onDestroyView/onDestroy/onDetach/onStop` methods of the 3 tab fragments not to be called. When I changed to use the `getChildFragmentManager` everything was OK.

If you want you can check the docs for the two methods:

> getChildFragmentManager():

Return a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments inside of this Fragment.

> getSupportFragmentManager():

Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated with this fragment’s activity.

Comment: I highly doubt this will change anything.

Comment: can you suggest some reason for your answer ?

Comment: i don't have proper reason but i face some white screen problem while changing screen orientation while using fragment at that time i have found this solution and this worked for me. and i also write in my question "may this will work".

Comment: <activity android:name=".yourActivity" 
      android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" . this is also work while screen orientation change but some time while fragment goes in onpause mode and some time later user back on this fragment at that time also this problem occurs so in that case my solution will work.

Comment: ok thanks for pointing out. I was asking because I was also using getSupportFragmentManager, but it had these issues I better be start using getFragmentManager.

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager and getFragmentManager is different issue. i have pointed diff between  getSupportFragmentManager or getFragmentManager vs getChildFragmentManager.

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager and getFragmentManager is related to activity and getChildFragmentManager is related to fragment.

Comment: yes.. it was a typo. I meant getChildFragmentManager.

Comment: ohk. or if you want some more details about this so may this ans help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740445/what-is-difference-between-getsupportfragmentmanager-and-getchildfragmentmanag

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your `Activity` does not reload every time orientation changes, you should declare `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in your manifest. This ensures the state of the 'Activity' is retained and not reloaded after orientation changes.