# IllegalArgumentException when calling new Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, illegalargumentexception

In my MainActivity I have a fragment which I replace by an other fragment class.

Replace fragment in MainActivity:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                .commit();
```

XML of MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
</FrameLayout>
```

This works fine.

The problem is now in my Fragment class. I want to call a new Activty (DetailRfrdPastActivity) from the fragment class. As soon as I add an element to the DetailRfrdPastActivity XML the app stops with the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0071
>   (com.scherrer.robin.chvote:id/touch_outside) for fragment
>   MainFragment{610d48e #0 id=0x7f0c0071}
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1098)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

In the fragment class I start the activity like this:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, FlexibleAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

public static MainFragment newInstance() {
    return new MainFragment();
}

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private FlexibleAdapter<IFlexible> mAdapter;
private List<IFlexible> originalItems;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvRef);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    this.mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    originalItems = AdapterData.getRfrdList();

    mAdapter = new FlexibleAdapter<>(AdapterData.getRfrdList());
    mAdapter.showAllHeaders();
    mAdapter.initializeListeners(this);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.enableStickyHeaders();
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    List<IFlexible> copyOriginalItems = new ArrayList<>(originalItems);

    mAdapter.setSearchText(query);
    mAdapter.filterItems(copyOriginalItems);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onItemClick(int itemPosition) {
    IFlexible clickedItem = mAdapter.getItem(itemPosition);

    if (clickedItem instanceof ItemRfrdPast) {
        Intent detailRfrdPast = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), DetailRfrdPastActivity.class);
        detailRfrdPast.putExtra("pastRfrd", ((ItemRfrdPast) clickedItem).getPastRfrd());
        getActivity().startActivity(detailRfrdPast);
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

XML of Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/lvRef"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<include layout="@layout/sticky_header_layout"/>
```

The DetailRfrdPastActivity is the child activity of MainActivity.
I can't figure out where the error is because the fragment and the called activity should have nothing to do with each other.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.DetailRfrdPastActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity" >

    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: show your full code for fragments

Comment: Try replacing `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()` with `getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()`.

Comment: @Vickyexpert added the fragment code

Comment: Have you added the new activity in you manifest?

Comment: @Kushan Yes, you can see my manifest.xml above

Comment: @android-ftw Did you get some exception after replacing ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna No, the replacing of the fragment works fine. The problem occurs only if I add an item to the xml of the calles activity.

Comment: No no I am not talking about replacing fragment, See my comment above.

Comment: com.scherrer.robin.chvote:id/touch_outside -> the view for this id is missing. Check your xmls for this id and your code for where you tried to access it.

Comment: likely that its inside the Viewholder of your adapter for the recycler view

Comment: use this it may help you;
private static myfragment = new MainFragment();
public static MainFragment newInstance() {
 if (myfragment == null)
  myfragment = new MainFragment();
    return myfragment;
}

Comment: just check in R.java, what is this ID indicating "0x7f0c0071" ?

Comment: @Vickyexpert R.java: public static final int container=0x7f0c0071;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ftw, I think that setting an onClickListener from the ViewHolder and invoking a callback with the selected item will do fine.

For Instance:

From FlexibleAdapter class

```
public interface OnIFlexibleClickListener {

    void onIFlexibleClick(IFlexible iFlexible);

}

private OnIFlexibleClickListener listener;

public setOnIFlexibleClickListener(OnIFlexibleClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public IFlexible getIFlexible(int position) {
        return iFlexibleList.get(position); //Your iFlexible List
}

public class FindViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView textView; //Replace the TextView with your own view.

    public FindViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView;
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onIFlexibleClick(getIFlexible(getAdapterPosition()));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

From MainFragment class, implement OnIFlexibleClickListener

```
@Override
public void onIFlexibleClick(IFlexible iFlexible) {
    if (iFlexible instanceof ItemRfrdPast) {
        ItemRfrdPast itemRfrdPast = ((ItemRfrdPast) iFlexible).getPastRfrd()

        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DetailRfrdPastActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PAST_RFRD, itemRfrdPast); //public static final String PAST_RFRD = "pastRfrd";
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, DetailRfrdPastActivity.REQUEST_CODE); //create a public static final int REQUEST_CODE
    }
}
```

I think that this should fix it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing that a view of id : **id/touch_outside** is missing from your MainFragment xml file. Please check this id in your xml as well as the included XMLs

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
```

**with**

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
```

**Why is so ?**

> May be because it can't find the Fragment with the given ID because it's in a different `FragmentManager`.

refer the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14775322/5067493)

Comment: getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction() is only working in an fragment and not in a activity. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yah you are right. I also didn't try that but what if you use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getChildFragmentManager()` full as it is. ? Try once if not working I will delete this ans.