# Content of ViewPager disappears when navigating back and forth using Navigation Components

Tags: java, android, navigation, android-jetpack

After migrating my navigation to the new Jetpack Navigation Component, I found that after navigating back and forth using the the libraries, the content/layout of the first two fragments in my ViewPager disappears. After clicking through the tabs, it comes back though.

At first I thought it was because of the errors that I saw in the logcat, but after fixing them, the problem was still there.

Here is the code of my MainActivity:

```
private Toolbar toolbar;

private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bindResources();

    // Setup Toolbar & Navigation Component
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setupNavigation();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_options, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void setupNavigation() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph())
            .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
            .build();

    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}
```

Here is the code of my ViewPagerAdapter:

```
private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public void addFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment, String title) {
    fragmentList.add(fragment);
    fragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentList.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
```

This is my HomeFragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    bindResources(view);

    // ViewPager
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new TodayFragment(), getString(R.string.tab_today_title));
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new PriorityFragment(), getString(R.string.tab_priority_title));
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new PlannedFragment(), getString(R.string.tab_planned_title));
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new TasksFragment(), getString(R.string.tab_tasks_title));
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    // TabLayout
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Java:** I fixed the problem by replacing

```
= new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
```

with

```
= new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

**Kotlin:** By replacing

```
= ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager)
```

with

```
= ViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
```

Comment: I was using `getFragmentManager()` inside a support Fragment, which is effectively the same as `getSupportFragmentManager()` from the activity, and replacing it with `getChildFragmentManager()` worked for me.

Comment: I had the same issue and this solved it. Do you know to explain why this is happening? And it still reloads. Is there a way to avoid it reloading?

Comment: here's is the why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14775322/2213616