# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0037 for fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragmenttransaction

I'm working on an app where I have to implement the `onClick` method on the fragment. When a button is clicked I want to open another fragment, but I'm facing an error with fragment id.

I used fragment manager and fragment transaction in the `onClick` method like below:

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
val fm = childFragmentManager
val ft = fm.beginTransaction()
ft.add(R.layout.fragment_extended_subscribers, ExtendedSubscribersFragment())
ft.addToBackStack(null)
ft.commit()
```

I also tried to add an id to FrameLayout and add it to fragment transaction but still the same error:

```
ft.add(R.id.fragment_for_subs,ExtendedSubscribersFragment())
```

The logcat error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0037 (al.mgr.ekranet:layout/fragment_extended_subscribers) for fragment ExtendedSubscribersFragment{d6186df #0 id=0x7f0d0037}
```

Here is my `onCreateView` function:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_extended_subscribers, container, false)
    getAllSubscribers()
    return view
```

Here is the layout associated with the fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_for_subs"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".homeFragments.ExtendedSubscribersFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/all_subscribers_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: An `R.layout` there is just wrong, and will always throw that Exception. You need to specify the `R.id` for the `ViewGroup` that the `Fragment` is being placed into, not one in the `Fragment`'s own layout.

Comment: @MikeM. I also tried using id like this: ft.add(R.id.fragment_for_subs,ExtendedSubscribersFragment())  but still the same error

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that in the question. Which layout is `fragment_for_subs` in?

Comment: Can you please post your `onCreateView` funciton? And the layout as well?

Comment: Can you please post your `fragment_extended_subscribers.xml` layout file as well?

Comment: @ReazMurshed I posted my fragment

Comment: "You need to specify the `R.id` for the `ViewGroup` that the `Fragment` is being placed into, not one in the `Fragment`'s own layout."

Comment: Can you show me an example how can I do

Comment: You don't need an example. You already have almost everything. You just need to pass the right `R.id`. Where are you trying to put `ExtendedSubscribersFragment`?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
    override fun onClick(v:View?) {
        // Change this to
        //-----------------------
//        val fm = childFragmentManager
        // this
        //-----------------------
        val fm = fragmentManager

        val ft = fm.beginTransaction()
        // Change: layout -> id
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_for_subs, ExtendedSubscribersFragment())
        ft.addToBackStack(null)
        ft.commit()
    }
```

For more info: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14775322/6076979)

Comment: Please share crash log.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0037 (al.mgr.ekranet:layout/fragment_extended_subscribers) for fragment ExtendedSubscribersFragment{d6186df #0 id=0x7f0d0037}

Comment: I again edited my answer, please try this without any change.

Comment: still the same, I don't understand this