# Different types of fragmentManagers

Tags: android, fragmentmanager

There are several different kinds of fragmentManagers in Android: `parentFragmentManager`, `childFragmentManager`, `supportFragmentManager` and plain `fragmentManager`, which is already deprecated. But what are the principal differences between them?

Answer (score 1):

**FragmentManager** is responsible for all runtime management of fragments including adding, removing, hiding, showing, or otherwise navigating between fragments. Plain **fragmentManager** was used for fragments that come from pure android (and behaviour of this fragments can be changed by vendors). So guys from Google introduced [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library) and started providing many android components as dependencies.

And **supportFragmentManager** comes into play. It completely replaces old **fragmentManager**. And if you use fragments from Support Library, then you should use **supportFragmentManager** for work with fragments.

**ChildFragmentManager:**

> Return a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments inside of this Fragment.

So this manager is used for nested navigation inside fragment. For example you have some kind of HomeFragment which has container and you want to show nested fragments inside that fragment.

More info: [SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740445/what-is-difference-between-getsupportfragmentmanager-and-getchildfragmentmanag/14775322), [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html), [ChildFragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager())