# Fragments in backStack

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have ViewPager that has 3 tabs. Tab(3) includes 2 fragments (A) --> (B).

```
Tab(1)
Tab(2)
Tab(3) --> (B) --> (C)
```

The way I replace fragments in Tab(3):

```
FragmentTransaction trans = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            trans.replace(R.id.B_container, new FragmentC().newInstance(), "C");
            trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            trans.addToBackStack("B->C");
            trans.commit();
```

When I'm in (B) and I'm hitting a button it takes me straight to Tab(3), skipping (A).
Here is the code from button in (B):

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
                fm.popBackStack();
            }
```

Everything works good.
**The problem is when I'm in (B) but then I go to Tab(1) or Tab(2) and hit the button after it doesn't work.**
Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.
Thank you.

**//======================================================================**

I tried to replace etActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() with getChildFragmentMaganer().
Since the regular way of popBackStack() wasn't working anymore I had to modify it.
Now it works and I have the same problem tho.

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            for (Fragment frag : fm.getFragments()) {
                    FragmentManager childFm = frag.getChildFragmentManager();
                    if (childFm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                        childFm.popBackStack();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **getChildFragmentManager()** to get your fragment manager. From my experience, when i'm inside a fragment and i try to place another fragment inside it, I use getChildFragmentManager.

Comment: How do I popBackStack() in case of getChildFragmentManager() ? Thank you.

Comment: It's pretty much the same fragment manager as the one you are already using. so you can do the same operations to it. checkout this guy's description of getChildFragmentManager... https://stackoverflow.com/a/14775322/12935148