# frangment landscape how replace correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i have an app with many fragments. this is layout on horizontal mode:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.map.manager.ListUser"
          android:id="@+id/listuser_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.map.manager.DetailApp"
          android:id="@+id/detailapp_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />   

</LinearLayout>
```

i can see my fragments correcty but if i do this:

```
            DetailUser appFrag = (DetailUser)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailuser_fragment);

            if (appFrag != null) {
                // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

                // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
                appFrag.updateAppointmentView(position);

            } 
            else {
            DetailUser dtuser = new DetailUser();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.detailapp_fragment, dtuser);
            transaction.commit();
```

i can replace fragments but i can see old fragment into backgroud..
i read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907673/android-cant-replace-one-fragment-with-another) i can't replace static fragments but how add it dynamically? (more than one into horizontal mode..) Can i replace a fragment without knowing old fragment?

Comment: You can use framelayout as container for fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Container for fragments:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/fragmentLayout"
    >

     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout1"
        android:layout_width="313dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
     </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/framelayout2" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>



//Adding Detailuser fragment to framelayout1:

    DetailUser dtuser = new DetailUser();
            FragmentTransaction transaction =    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.framelayout1, dtuser);
            transaction.commit();
//Adding another fragment to framelayout1:

    Fragment frag = new Fragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction =    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.framelayout2, frag);
            transaction.commit();

//Replacing fragment in framelayout:

    Fragment2 frag2 = new Fragment2();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.framelayout1, frag);
                transaction.commit();
```

Comment: no you replace i want both dtuser and frag. if i add dtuser and frag i have overlapping..

Comment: Code fixed, now you have dynamically added two framents in same layout

Comment: Replace fragment that framelayout1 is currently containing. If framelayout contains dtuser Fragment, frag2 will replace it.

Comment: thanks! for replace fragments (and dynamic menu) is there an effective design pattern? (if i replace list modify menu for example) without the heavy use of variables.. thanks!