# Display settings using "Settings" in triple-dot menu

Tags: android, preferencefragment

I'm setting up some basic settings for my android application, and I'm having some problems. First of all, I couldn't figure out how to use the triple-dot menu in the top right of the action bar to open Settings. So I temporarily created a button that calls chooseSettings:

[image: a button]

```
    public void chooseSettings(View view) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PreferenceActivity()).commit();
}
```

This is the code for my PreferenceActivity class:

```
public class PreferenceActivity extends PreferenceFragment {
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
 }
}
```

Which kind of works. That results in my screen looking like this:.

[image: this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Settings in Overflow Menu**

In order to use the Settings in the overflow menu, you need to override the [onOptionsItemSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29) method, if not already and handle the correct id.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        // Code to show settings.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Replace `R.id.action_settings` with the id of your menu item.

**Displaying the PreferenceFragment**

As you have shown in your image, your preferences screen is overlapping the existing layout.

Note that you can only replace a fragment you added [dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907673/android-cant-replace-one-fragment-with-another).

I'm guessing the xml for your screen that has the buttons Guess Country and Guess Flags was inflated and was not dynamically added as a fragment so by adding the preference fragment it would simply be displayed overlapping.

**Solution**

One way you can go about this is by creating and starting a new activity which will load your preferences fragment.

For example, if you create class called `SettingsActivity` which will load the preferences (Don't forget to add to AndroidManifest):

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PreferenceActivity()).commit();
    }
}
```

Then in your `onOptionsItemSelected`, you can start the settings activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Otherwise, you would need to change your main layout to use something like a frame layout so that you can add/remove/replace fragments properly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, I really appreciate it. It works perfectly! Seriously, thank you, I couldn't understand this anywhere else. You said it perfectly and clearly :D.