# FragmentTransaction.replace() not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `ListFragment` displaying a list of items that created by the user. I have a `ListView` with it's id set to "@android:id/list" and a `TextView` with the id "@android:id/empty".

I have an action bar button to display a fragment to allow the user to create more entries for the list. Here is the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment frag = null;

    // Right now I only have code for the addCourse() fragment, will add more soon
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.addCourse:
        frag = new AddCourseFragment();
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // The support library is being dumb and replace isn't actually 
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .remove(this).add(getId(), frag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    return true;

}
```

The AddCourseFragment code is as follows:

```
public class AddCourseFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_addcourse, container, false);
//      if (view.findViewById(R.id.timesFrame)!=null) {
        Fragment timesFrag = new TimesFragment();
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.timesFrame, timesFrag).commit();
//      }
    return view;
    }
}
```

As expected, when the list is unpopulated, android shows the text in the `TextView`. I then hit the add course button and this happens: [image]
It shows the empty text as well as the new fragment.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) when you need to add `Fragments` programmatically, you should add them to an existing `ViewGroup`.

So I removed the `Fragment` from the xml and used `FrameLayout` component in the `replace()` method.

You can also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293850/fragment-duplication-on-fragment-transaction).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

An other problem that solved the issue in my case were diffentent API imports.

Make sure, that you use "support.v4" or the "original" implementations from API 11 and do not mix them. (this can happen, in my case: TransactionManager was v4 and the Activity an older version, or the other way around)

Answer (score 2):

Give a background color to the main layout of the childFragment.

Like android:background="#FFFFFF"

This worked for me!!!!

Comment: Views are still there, you just can't see them.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is use LinearLayout Instead of fragment

```
 <Fragment
        android:name="path/to.package.MyClass"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
         />
```

USE it like this

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:name="path/to.package.MyClass"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
         />
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved changing the RelativeLayout for a LinearLayout... Hope it helps!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground">


    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```