# Android Fragments Not Being Replaced Properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

Unfortunately when I attempt to switch between tabs, I get an error similar to this person's ([FragmentTransaction.replace() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446935/fragmenttransaction-replace-not-working)), where the list of text from my first tab appears in the background of every other fragment. I did follow the recommendation to use a FrameLayout with a container, so that I could simply add or delete the relevant fragments when the tab was switched (which was also recommended here [Fragment duplication on Fragment Transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293850/fragment-duplication-on-fragment-transaction)). I am attempting to use @Niek's TabListener solution from [Switching fragments within tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502786/switching-fragments-within-tab), yet the problem still persists.

All help will be most appreciated, thank you so much for your time.

From my MainActivity:

```
//Making an Action Bar
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionbar.setTitle("MyApp");

    //Creating the Tabs
    ActionBar.Tab Frag1Tab = actionbar.newTab().setText("BlackList");
    ActionBar.Tab Frag2Tab = actionbar.newTab().setText("TreeMenu");
    ActionBar.Tab Frag3Tab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Map");
    ActionBar.Tab Frag4Tab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Help");

    //Fragments (Underlying Classes for Each Class)
    Fragment1 = new BlackistFragment();
    Fragment2 = new TreeMenuFragment();
    Fragment3 = new Fragment_3();
    Fragment4 = new Fragment_4();

    //Adding Tab Listeners 
    //new TabListener<StationsFragment>(this, "stations", StationsFragment.class)
    Frag1Tab.setTabListener(new TabListener<BlackistFragment>(this, "frag1", BlackistFragment.class));
    Frag2Tab.setTabListener(new TabListener<TreeMenuFragment>(this, "frag2", TreeMenuFragment.class));
    Frag3Tab.setTabListener(new TabListener<Fragment_3>(this, "frag3", Fragment_3.class));
    Frag4Tab.setTabListener(new TabListener<Fragment_4>(this, "frag4", Fragment_4.class));


    //Adding Tabs to Action Bar
    actionbar.addTab(Frag1Tab);
    actionbar.addTab(Frag2Tab);
    actionbar.addTab(Frag3Tab);
    actionbar.addTab(Frag4Tab);
```

The Tab Listener...

```
public class TabListener<T extends SherlockFragment> implements com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener {
    private final SherlockFragmentActivity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    private SherlockFragment mFragment;

    public TabListener(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> class1) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = class1;
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        SherlockFragment preInitializedFragment = (SherlockFragment) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
        if (preInitializedFragment == null) {
            mFragment = (SherlockFragment) SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            ft.attach(preInitializedFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        SherlockFragment preInitializedFragment = (SherlockFragment) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);

        if (preInitializedFragment != null) {
            ft.detach(preInitializedFragment);
        } else if (mFragment != null) {
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}
```

The onCreateView from my BlackistFragment Tab (the one that appears in all other tabs..). Note that it extends SherlockFragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blacklist, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    //Making BlackList 
    TreeSet<BlacklistWord> theSet =  MainActivity.getInstance().datasource.GetAllWords();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(BlacklistWord i :theSet){
        System.out.println(i.getWord());
        list.add(i.getWord());
    }
    Collections.sort(list);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ((BaseAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

    ((ViewGroup) listView.getParent()).removeView(listView);
    container.addView(listView);

    return view;
}
```

My second Fragment class...

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    MainActivity.getInstance().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.treemenu, container, false);

    //Auto-Complete
    AutoCompleteTextView autoView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String[] itemOptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.edit_message);

    ArrayAdapter<String> theAdapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemOptions);
    autoView.setAdapter(theAdapter);
    ((BaseAdapter) autoView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    //      ((ViewGroup) autoView.getParent()).removeView(autoView);
    Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.post_blacklist_button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AutoCompleteTextView editText=(AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
            String blackListItem = editText.getText().toString();
            editText.setText("");
            MainActivity.getInstance().postBlackListItem(blackListItem);
            //refreshes the rest 
            MainActivity.getInstance().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
    initViews(view);
    if(view != null) { return view; }

    ((ViewGroup) autoView.getParent()).removeView(autoView);
    container.addView(autoView);
    MainActivity.getInstance().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be easier to show you how I have it implemented than to modify your code. Then you can easily adapt it to your use case.

Edit: I have changed some variables to match your program.

Here is the class implementing TabListener:

```
public class CustomTabListener implements TabListener {
    private Fragment fragment;

    public CustomTabListener(Fragment frag){
        fragment = frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);      
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //Tab Reselected....    
    }

    }
```

Then you can add tabs like so...

```
private void addTabs() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setTitle("MyApp");

    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("BlackList")
            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener(Fragment1)));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("TreeMenu")
            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener(Fragment2)));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Map")
            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener(Fragment3)));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Help")
            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener(Fragment4)));
}
```

All you have to do is pass it the fragment.

Comment: Hi Corey, thank you for your response. it appears like the one significant difference is your last two lines involved Drawable. I was wondering from where you stored your R.drawable.gradient_rectangle, since I have no indication that it exists within my project.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't relevant to your question, I have removed those and renamed some variables to match what you have so far.  You still have to create those fragments before running that.

Comment: Hi Corey, unfortunately your code does not solve my ubiquitous fragment issue. I have already defined the tabs in the form...   Fragment1 = new BlackistFragment(); etc as seen in my original post.

Comment: Ok, it would appear that the error is within one of your Fragment classes.  Could you edit your original post and add the errors from your logcat?

Comment: Hi Corey, thank you for being so patient. No errors are being thrown. I have added my TreeMenuFragment onCreateView as well if that helps.