# How to find Relative Layout Contains Fragment or Not

Tags: android, layout, fragment, android-relativelayout

I am trying to add and Remove a fragment in a relative layout. If in the relative layout (fragment container) is empty then add the fragment if not replace the fragment .

How to check whether the layout is empty or not , so that i do not get the error saying fragment already added.

Comment: use myFragment.isInlayout()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
YourFragment dFrag = (YourFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.detailfragment);

if (dFrag != null && dFrag.isInLayout()) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would be an answer, but i'd recommend you to use FragmentTransaction like this:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

if(yourOldFragment.isAdded()) {
    ft.replace(R.id.your_container, yourNewFragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

You can also have a look this link : [Fragment duplication on Fragment Transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293850/fragment-duplication-on-fragment-transaction)